# php check mail by imap and show its contents during a certain time

Tags: php, mysql, email, imap, timing

Following situation: i have 2 php scripts. the first one (index.php) checks every 2 minutes if there is a new mail by php_imap and if so it writes the contents to a mysql db. The 2nd script (show_mail.php) shows the contents out of the mysql db during an hour. if no new mail arrives, show_mail.php switch to index.php, but if there is a new mail, show_mail.php has to show the contents for an hour...

i tried by a timer on index.php (javascript: window.settimeout(2000)) and a second timer on show_mail.php, but it stucks.

How can i solve this?  thanks for your help!

Comment: It doesn't seem a good idea to run two scripts continuously. If you're working on Linux you could use cron jobs for this. It runs the scripts when needed. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: if you want to achive these thing you need to use node.js that will work perfectly and achieve your functionality. Visit here https://nodejs.org/en/ for more detail.

Comment: i have to make this with timers because the scripts turn on a webserver at my internet provider and there i have no chance to go to the operating system